# Showing the composition of invertible functions $g \circ f$ is invertible with inverse $f^{-1} \circ g^{-1}$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-verification, elementary-set-theory, proof-writing, proof-explanation

> Let $ f : X \rightarrow Y$ and $g : Y \rightarrow Z$ be invertible functions. Prove that $g \circ f : X \rightarrow Z$ is invertible and that $(g \circ f ) ^{-1} = f^{-1} \circ g^{-1} $

Would this suffice as a proof?

$$\begin{align}
(g \circ f) \circ (f^{-1} \circ g^{-1}) &= g \circ ((f \circ f^{-1}) \circ g^{-1})\\
&= g \circ (I_Y \circ g^{-1})\\
&= g \circ g^{-1}\\
&= I_X\\
(f^{-1} \circ g^{-1}) \circ (g \circ f) &= (f^{-1} \circ (g^{-1} \circ g)) \circ f\\
&= (f^{-1} \circ I_Y) \circ f\\
&= f^{-1} \circ f\\
&= I_Z
\end{align}$$

Comment: That really depends on the context in which you were given this problem.

Comment: Context in regards to what specific topic this question was from in my textbook?

Comment: I am a tad confused, beneficial comments to answers are being deleted. Is my approach correct? Corrections are welcomed!

Comment: Hi David. The deleted answer was, in my opinion, very unhelpful. Your approach is essentially fine. I posted a response below.

Comment: You've shown that $(g \circ f)^-1 = f^-1 \circ g^-1$, but you do have to explicitly say that we're going to assume that $f^-1 \circ g^-1$ is the inverse of $(g \circ f)$. Also, as mentioned in one of the answers to this post (now deleted), you have not proved that $g \circ f$ is invertible

Comment: @ K.M. Thanks for comment. So how would i prove that $g \circ f$ is invertible. I thought I did that which is why I ask.

Comment: @K.M This is not the case. David makes no assumption that $f^{-1} \circ g^{-1}$ is $(g \circ f)^{-1}$. David takes $f^{-1} \circ g^{-1}$ and shows through the associativity of composition that it inverts $g \circ f$

Comment: @David: http://math.jhu.edu/~jpaschke/Extra%20Handouts/What%20Makes%20a%20Good%20Proof.pdf is a pretty good proof.

Comment: @David: In regards to your proof, it's correct. I was mainly thinking in terms of the proof that I posted earlier. But from p.23-24 of http://www.cs.cornell.edu/courses/cs2800/2015sp/lnotes/14_functions.pdf your method is correct

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would accept this as a proof on an undergraduate homework assignment.

The only comment I would make is that it needs some English sentences to provide context to what you're doing and why.

Try opening with

> Consider the function $f^{-1} \circ g^{-1}$, which is guaranteed to exist because (...)

before moving on with

> Now we verify that $f^{-1} \circ g^{-1}$ inverts $g\circ f$. First consider the composition from the left, which can be done because (...)

and then

> (...) now consider the composition from the right, which can be done because (...)

and then a statement with your conclusion.

Generally blocks of mathematics should be delimited with English statements. You have two main mathematical "thoughts" in what you wrote, so need to wrap them both, as well as the unspoken "thought" about using/examining $f^{-1} \circ g^{-1}$ in the first place.

Comment: Thank you very much for your feedback, really appreciate it. And yes i am an undergrad math and stats student. Will definitely use your feedback when I edit this proof for homework submission.